# Skipping weekends and splitting days with an event block of 3 days using fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I have a question relating to the plugin called "fullcalendar" that can be viewed here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-data

What I would like to achieve is a modification to my current script located below on my jsfiddle link. Which is to create a event split block when the external event is dragged and dropped near for example Friday, the event block of 3 days would split and would skip saturday and sunday and place the rest of the event block on Monday and Tuesday instead.

My script below currently places the external event of three days on any three days following the day you place the event.

JSFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/rayshinn/G3VTa/

To create the 3 days block I added the following

```
var threeDayBlock = new Date(date.getTime());
threeDayBlock.setDate(threeDayBlock.getDate() + 2);

copiedEventObject.end = threeDayBlock;
```

Comment: Is your idea that it would end up actually making 2 events?  One on Friday and one Monday-Tuesday ?  Or should it be one event that goes from Friday-Tuesday?

Comment: Hi @Ryley thanks for taking your time to answer! as for your question, it should be the same event.

Comment: So you don't mind if the event is actually 5 days long?

Comment: Hi @Ryley The event should be 3 days long. Just split from friday-Monday-Tuesday. With it avoiding the weekends. Thanks again for the assistance. I'm just a bit puzzled on how I should approach this situation.

Comment: OK... I don't think FullCalendar supports that, at least I don't see any mention of it in the documentation.  So you may be out of luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is similar to the previous https://stackoverflow.com/a/17868692/975520, but extend it by supporting the required `four days events` (and can be simply switched to five, I'm thinking about a solution without the ifs, working on it...) and improving the principal if statement.

Here for a 5 days event: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/z27a2/6/ the script build an array of calendar events by checking if the starting day and following days are in the same week, if not split the event in two different element of the array. At the end the code loop this array and create the event on the calendar.

I'm minding about a better solution, but for now this is it

Code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        var firstDay = new Date(date.getTime());
        while (firstDay.getDay() == 0 || firstDay.getDay() == 6) {
            firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1);
        }

        var secondDay = new Date(firstDay.getTime());
        do {
            secondDay.setDate(secondDay.getDate() + 1);
        } while (secondDay.getDay() == 0 || secondDay.getDay() == 6);

        var thirdDay = new Date(secondDay.getTime());
        do {
            thirdDay.setDate(thirdDay.getDate() + 1);
        } while (thirdDay.getDay() == 0 || thirdDay.getDay() == 6);

        var fourthDay = new Date(thirdDay.getTime());
        do {
            fourthDay.setDate(fourthDay.getDate() + 1);
        } while (fourthDay.getDay() == 0 || fourthDay.getDay() == 6);

        var dateAdd = new Array();

        if (getWeekNr(firstDay) == getWeekNr(fourthDay)) {
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            copiedEventObject.start = firstDay;
            copiedEventObject.end = fourthDay;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);
        } else if (getWeekNr(firstDay) == getWeekNr(thirdDay)) {
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            copiedEventObject.start = firstDay;
            copiedEventObject.end = thirdDay;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);

            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            copiedEventObject.start = fourthDay;
            copiedEventObject.end = fourthDay;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);
        } else if (getWeekNr(firstDay) == getWeekNr(secondDay)) {
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            copiedEventObject.start = firstDay;
            copiedEventObject.end = secondDay;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);

            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            copiedEventObject.start = thirdDay;
            copiedEventObject.end = fourthDay;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);
        } else {
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            copiedEventObject.start = firstDay;
            copiedEventObject.end = firstDay;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);

            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            copiedEventObject.start = secondDay;
            copiedEventObject.end = fourthDay;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);
        }

        $.each(dateAdd, function (index, value) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', value, true);
        });

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/z27a2/5/

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in solution to do what you want and a multiple day event can't skip days inside of the interval; so I enjoy to find one, here is my solution!

The script work like this; for the given start date I find the correct following two days according to weekends and set three variables with the single dates.
For every date I find the number of week and using it I find if I have to create a multiple day event or more events.

The most relevant code is:

```
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getTime());
    while (firstDay.getDay() == 0 || firstDay.getDay() == 6) {
        firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1);
    }

    var secondDay = new Date(firstDay.getTime());
    do {
        secondDay.setDate(secondDay.getDate() + 1);
    } while (secondDay.getDay() == 0 || secondDay.getDay() == 6);

    var thirdDay = new Date(secondDay.getTime());
    do {
        thirdDay.setDate(thirdDay.getDate() + 1);
    } while (thirdDay.getDay() == 0 || thirdDay.getDay() == 6);
```

to check the week of the date and check if weeks dates are the same I use the function:

```
function getWeekNr(today)
{
    Year = takeYear(today);
    Month = today.getMonth();
    Day = today.getDate();
    now = Date.UTC(Year,Month,Day+1,0,0,0);
    var Firstday = new Date();
    Firstday.setYear(Year);
    Firstday.setMonth(0);
    Firstday.setDate(1);
    then = Date.UTC(Year,0,1,0,0,0);
    var Compensation = Firstday.getDay();
    if (Compensation > 3) Compensation -= 4;
    else Compensation += 3;
    NumberOfWeek =  Math.round((((now-then)/86400000)+Compensation)/7);
    return NumberOfWeek;
}
function takeYear(theDate)
{
    x = theDate.getYear();
    var y = x % 100;
    y += (y < 38) ? 2000 : 1900;
    return y;
}
```

every range is added to an object array ad used to fill the calendar using:

```
    $.each(dateAdd, function (index, value) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', value, true);
    });
```

Final code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            var firstDay = new Date(date.getTime());
            while (firstDay.getDay() == 0 || firstDay.getDay() == 6) {
                firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1);
            }

            var secondDay = new Date(firstDay.getTime());
            do {
                secondDay.setDate(secondDay.getDate() + 1);
            } while (secondDay.getDay() == 0 || secondDay.getDay() == 6);

            var thirdDay = new Date(secondDay.getTime());
            do {
                thirdDay.setDate(thirdDay.getDate() + 1);
            } while (thirdDay.getDay() == 0 || thirdDay.getDay() == 6);

            var dateAdd = new Array();

            if (getWeekNr(firstDay)==getWeekNr(secondDay) && getWeekNr(firstDay)==getWeekNr(thirdDay)) {
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                copiedEventObject.start = firstDay;
                copiedEventObject.end = thirdDay;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);
            }
            else {
                if (getWeekNr(firstDay)==getWeekNr(secondDay)){
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                    copiedEventObject.start = firstDay;
                    copiedEventObject.end = secondDay;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                    dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);

                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                    copiedEventObject.start = thirdDay;
                    copiedEventObject.end = thirdDay;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                    dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);
                }
                else {
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                    copiedEventObject.start = firstDay;
                    copiedEventObject.end = firstDay;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                    dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);

                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                    copiedEventObject.start = secondDay;
                    copiedEventObject.end = thirdDay;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                    dateAdd.push(copiedEventObject);
                }
            }

            $.each(dateAdd, function (index, value) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', value, true);
            });

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    });
```

Working demo: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Suppose I want to change the three day span to 4 days. What do I need to add in that if and else if statement you have created? Could you explain your approach on that?

Comment: Create a new var fourthDay, calculate it checking if w.e. or not, implement the if to handle the fourth day. I'm on mobile cant add more info now

Comment: I'm having some issues trying to adjust your if (getWeekNr(firstDay)==getWeekNr(secondDay) && getWeekNr(firstDay)==getWeekNr(thirdDay)) { and on wards to match the extension of event days criteria, do you mind showing me what you meant on your reply in the fiddle? Thanks again for all your effort, I truly appreciate your help in this.

Comment: I'm only on mobile for a week, so I can't be too helpful now :-( the test check if the days of the event fall in the same week, if not create different events

Comment: Hey Edward, thank you again for your help in this question. I was wondering when you have more access, if you could follow up on my above question. Would appreciate it a lot! Thank you.

Comment: wondering if you can follow up with the example of extending it to 4 days?

Comment: I'm back :-) you need assistance to extend the code to works on 4 days events?

Comment: I think this can work well with four days events: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/z27a2/5/, if ok I'll add a new answer with the code?

Comment: Hi @Edward would you mind extending it to 5 days for me to compare your if statements as well? I seem to get a bit confused after line 56 in the JS. Sorry for all the trouble! and yes please go ahead and add a new answer after so I can accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/z27a2/6/ the script build an array of calendar events by checking if the days are in the same week, if not split the event in two different element of the array. I'm minding about a better solution, but for now this is it