# Skip weekend and holiday in fullcalender from database

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar-scheduler

[Skipping weekends and splitting days with an event block of 3 days using fullcalender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814762/skipping-weekends-and-splitting-days-with-an-event-block-of-3-days-using-fullcal)

i just see this and looking for the demo in last answer

i want to make the event skip the weekend date and holiday without using dragevent i just want to you data from database

```
@foreach($taskpar as $task)
                {
                    resourceId: '{{$task->ID}}',
                    title: '<?php echo $i; ?> - {{$task->TASK_DESC}}',
                    start: '{{$task->TASK_STATSDATE}}',
                    @if ($task->duration == '1' OR $task->duration == '3')
                    end: '{{$task->TASK_ENDDATE}}',
                    @else
                    end: '{{$task->TASK_ENDDATE}}+40000',
                    @endif
                    @if ($task->status == 'Pending')
                    url: '{!! route('assignModal', ['id'=>$task->ID]) !!}',
                    @elseif($task->status == 'Complete')
                        eventColor: 'green',
                    @else 
                        url: '{!! route('assignModal', ['id'=>$task->ID]) !!}',
                    @endif
                    description: 'Duration : {{$task->duration}}  - {{$task->EMP_NAME}}'
                     <?php $i++;?> 
                },
                @endforeach
```

this is the code event i made but it still can't skip the weekend

http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/z27a2/4/

newbie in here ty